# USB Tethering shows as Ethernet

Tags: usb, network-interface, android, internet, mobile

I have NetworkManager on my Arch Linux machine. Output of `ifconfig`:

```
enp0s18f2u1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.241.167  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.241.255
        inet6 fe80::f4cb:ecbe:eb8e:c961  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 46:0b:4a:d9:56:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9132  bytes 11251343 (10.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6571  bytes 998708 (975.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 90:2b:34:96:0c:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 1021 (1021.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 1021 (1021.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`enp0s18f2u1` is my USB tethering interface. Why do I have `enp3s0`? Why does my connection speed drops to rock-bottom after I replug the cable until I reboot my PC?

dmesg:

```
[   31.007291] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   31.438343] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[   31.585979] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2004, bcdDevice= 2.23
[   31.585989] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   31.585995] usb 1-1: Product: Nokia 2.2
[   31.585999] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[   31.586003] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
[   31.664819] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   31.675846] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:12.2-1, RNDIS device, 92:38:f4:ee:51:a2
[   31.675882] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[   31.686275] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enp0s18f2u1: renamed from usb0
[   31.905225] kauditd_printk_skb: 7 callbacks suppressed

[ 1365.294661] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 1365.418013] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1365.672302] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2008, bcdDevice= 2.23
[ 1365.672313] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1365.672319] usb 1-1: Product: Nokia 2.2
[ 1365.672323] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[ 1365.672326] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625

[ 1375.172543] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1375.604696] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 1375.752534] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2004, bcdDevice= 2.23
[ 1375.752541] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1375.752544] usb 1-1: Product: Nokia 2.2
[ 1375.752546] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[ 1375.752549] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
[ 1375.754881] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:12.2-1, RNDIS device, be:c0:2b:4b:c4:a9
[ 1375.792804] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enp0s18f2u1: renamed from usb0
[ 1375.963532] kauditd_printk_skb: 1 callbacks suppressed
```

Why does `rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enp0s18f2u1: renamed from usb0` happens?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I have enp3s0?

Because you have some hardware in "position 3, slot 0" that is detected as an ethernet interface. If this is a PC, first step is to use `lspci` to find out more about what hardware you have, as it's probably some PCIe device.

> Why does my connection speed drops to rock-bottom after I replug an USB cable until I reboot my PC?

No idea, that needs debugging on what actually happens when you replug the cable. Start by looking at `dmesg`.

---

```
[ 1365.418013] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
```

This indicates an error while using USB. The second attempt 10 seconds later succeeded, but something is unstable, and I wouldn't be surprised if you find more USB errors when it "gets slow", or a slower USB rate on the second connection (check with `lsusb`). My first guess would be a hardware or firmware problem in your USB modem, and/or power supply issues.

> Why does rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enp0s18f2u1: renamed from usb0 happens?

Because Linux uses "predictable interface names", and they are made predictable by renaming them applying udev rules. Perfectly normal, and not related to your slow connection.

Comment: I can't find anything useful in the `dmesg`. I've updated my question with the output of it.

Comment: >and related to your slow connection. But how could interface name be related to connection speed?

Comment: "not related", of course.